# how can i change the checkbox attribute which are in the 9th column of a table

Tags: javascript

How to modify the checkbox attribute (checkbok in the 9th cells of the table MyTab) ?

MyTab contains 9 columns and the last is a checkbox.

None of the following code is working.

```
$('#MyTab tr').filter(':visible').each(function( index,element) {

     element.cells[8].attr('checked', true);

     $(this).attr('checked',true);

     $(this).prop('checked',true);

     $(element "input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked',true) ;

     element.cells[8].attr('checked', true);

     element.cells[8].prop('checked', true);

 });

HTML part = exemple with one row =
<table id="MyTab"  border=0 width=1400 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 class="table" >
<tr class='impair' onMouseOver="this.className='ModuleCorpsColorOver';" onMouseOut="this.className='impair';">
   <td>USER</td>
   <td>964469597</td> 
   <td>17231215</td>
   <td>450,60</td>
   <td>22-11-18</td>
   <td>08-10-18</td>
   <td>DOCUMENT1</td>
   <td>LIBELLE1</td>
   <td><input type='checkbox' class='inputNoBord' name='upd_statut[]' value='1' enable></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    ....
</tr>
</table>

I am also using following jquery =
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/sorttable.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery.filtertable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post your html code for this table?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to be more readable and remove the double text and comments.

Comment: _“the 8th is a checkbox”_ - and where do we start counting in JavaScript? `element.cells[8]` is accessing the _ninth_ cell of this table row element.

Comment: exact the ninth column instead of the 8th : element.cells[8] is the ninth column.

Comment: `element.cells[8]` is a reference to a native DOM element, not a jQuery object - so you can not call jQuery methods like `attr` on this, this should have thrown an error right away. (Did you even check the browser console?)

Comment: yes browser console return an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a class to the columns and directly access that element by class.

JQuery provides multiple ways to access any element in the DOM. I think the following should work for you.

```
$('tr.t-detail-row').find('td.t-detail-cell').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("td:first input:checkbox").prop("checked",true);`
could you try like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MyTab tr').filter(':visible').find('td:eq(8) input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

You can just use `:eq(8)` to directly filter only the 9th table cell of each row.

You don’t even need to loop over the elements, since in *setting* mode, `.prop` works on all elements in the collection.

Comment: OH YESSSSSS IT IS WORKING. BRAVO. THANK'S A LOT.